# File created with root and given other read permissions not even visible by user

Tags: permissions

I created a file by root and gave it the following permissions:

`-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    12 Nov 23 12:20 testFile`

When I switch to User and run `ls -al` I get every file except `testFile`. Its not even listed.

I expected to have it listed but only be able to execute and read it.

Why?

Comment: can you question and add the absolute path of the testFile and the result of the `ls -la` ?

Comment: Make sure the directory you are working in has privilege with the new user. The user should have +r-x access to it to even see the files listed.

Answer (score 1):

To list a file you need a `r+x` permissions on directory containing this file. So, please give us also output from `namei -l /full/path/to/file/file`. And just for sure `ls -ld /full/path/to/file`.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the namei example. I wasn't aware of this tool.

Comment: The OP said that they're able to list all files except that one. So it's not a problem of dir permissions.